# How do you create a default template?

Tags: page-template

I have several custom templates.  When I create a new page, custom templates (Thesis Skin Custom Template) shows "No Custom Template".  There are several to choose from in the drop down.

The problem is that any dynamic page will not use a template.  Is there a way to make a custom template the default for new pages?

Comment: Actually you don't need to do that. Just change the `page.php`'s layout and the thing is done. It's because when you are activating a default page template for all the pages, you are actually overriding the `page.php`'s default look. Isn't that?

Comment: main file page.php works for all pages defoult so you can add any changes  for template in this file wich will applied to all the defaoult pages.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking modifying page.php was the only way.  If I want page.php to look like one of the custom templates, I'll need to copy/paste pieces from a custom template into page.php?

Comment: Where page.php located?